# Return first letter of each word capitalized

Tags: c, cs50

I'm trying to write a function to take a string, and return the first letter of each word capitalized.

Eg: 'The sun in the sky' => TSITS

Here is my code. After tinkering quite a bit I manage to be able to compile; but seems like it only print the spaces of the string

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <cs50.h>   // typedef char *string; string GetString();

int main(void)
{
    string s = GetString();

    for (int i=0;i<strlen(s);i++){
        if(i == s[0] || s[i-1] == ' ' ){
            s[i] = toupper(s[i]);
            printf("%c",i);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

What's wrong with it?

Comment: `if (i == s[0]` What is that supposed to do?

Comment: What is `i == s[0]` supposed to test?

Comment: What is `string` and `GetString()`?

Comment: Why you are printing the index instead of the characters?

Comment: `i == s[0]` will never be true unless you really have  a very very long string or an empty string. `s[i-1]` is out of bound when `i == 0`.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than use `i == s[0]` (which likely was meant to be `i == 0`) simply keep track of the previous character.

```
char previous = ' ';

// Don't recalculate the length each time, just look for the null character
// for (int i=0;i<strlen(s);i++){
for (; *s; s++){
    if(previous == ' ' && isalpha((unsigned char) *s)) {
      printf("%c",toupper((unsigned char) *s));
      // or 
      putchar(toupper((unsigned char) *s));
    }
    previous = *s; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- `string` and `GetString` is used, but you didn't define them or you didn't disclose the command line or environment where they are defined.
- The condition `i == s[0]` is nonsense because it compares the index with the character code of the first character. It also may lead to invoking *undefined behavior* for out-of-range access of `s[-1]`.
- The printing statement `printf("%c",i);` is wrong because it prints the index instead of the character.

Try this code, which deals with the first line of the input:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
    char s[1024];
    char last_character = ' '; /* to deal with word lying on multiple chunks */

    /* repeat for the case where the line to deal with is too long to fit in one chunk */
    while (fgets(s, sizeof(s), stdin) != NULL) {
        int i;
        /* calling strlen() in every loop is not effective */
        for (i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++){
            /* check if currently looking at the first charater of each words */
            if(isalpha((unsigned char)s[i]) && (i == 0 ? last_character : s[i-1]) == ' '){
                /* cast to unsigned char to avoid undefined behavior invoked by passing out-of-range value */
                printf("%c", toupper((unsigned char)s[i]));
                /* incrementing i here may cause skipping the terminating null-character for the new loop condition, so remove it */
            }
        }
        if (i > 0) {
            /* save the last character in this chunk */
            last_character = s[i - 1];
            /* deal with only the first line */
            if (last_character == '\n') break;
        }
    }
    putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for a fast quite a through answer, I will need some time and a lot of googling to fully understand what's going on :)

Comment: Hint for googling: *ternary operator* is used in `(i == 0 ? last_character : s[i-1])`

Comment: Thanks for the hint, actually ternary operators might be one of the things I get, I come from Ruby :)

Answer (score 0):

```
string func(string s){
//take a string, and return the first letter of each word capitalized.
    char pre = ' ', curr;
    int new_i = 0;

    for(int org_i = 0; curr = s[org_i]; ++org_i){
        if(isspace(curr))
            pre = ' ';
        else if(pre == ' ')
            s[new_i++] = toupper(pre = curr);
    }
    s[new_i] = 0;
    return s;
}

int main(void){
    string s = GetString();

    puts(func(s));
    free(s);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite easy frankly.

```
//First the includes
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void) {
        string str = GetString(); //Here you should enter your string
        str[0] = toupper(str[0]); //Capitalize the first letter so you don't have to do extra checking in the for loop
        for (int i = 1; i < strlen(str); i++){ //Start from the second letter(or space) since index 0 is already capitalized
                if(str[i-1] == ' ') //Check if the previous character was a space
                        str[i] = toupper(str[i]); //Convert to uppercase
        }
        puts(str); //Print out the string, same thing as printf(str);
}
```

I hope I helped  :)